# I cannot resolve "redirect loop"

Tags: php, redirect

This webpage has a redirect loop.
The above has been discussed and answered broadly here but, after following the recommendations found here I still cannot resolve problem with "header("Location:...)".

The code is executed when user clicks a "forgotten password" link in email. The link has random string attached to it like ".../?trs=randomstringstoredindatabase".

When code executes:

if string is valid I get the following results:

```
Case with code lines "header...;: & "exit;" uncommented:
    URL in browser: http://localhost/pl_00_00/pl_process_forgot_password_back.php/pl_reset_password.php/index.php
    Chrome displays: This webpage has a redirect loop

Case with code lines "header...;: & "exit;" commented out:
    URL in browser: http://localhost/pl_00_00/pl_process_forgot_password_back.php/?trs=015df6fcf5bdcd4d9a339d5ca79d27a7 - correct
    Chrome displays echo: "Redirect to: pl_reset_password.php/?memid=11" - as expected
```

otherwise (string not valid):

```
Case with code lines "header...;: & "exit;" uncommented:
    URL in browser: http://localhost/pl_00_00/pl_process_forgot_password_back.php/index.php
    Chrome displays: This webpage has a redirect loop

Case with code lines "header...;: & "exit;" commented out:
    URL in browser: http://localhost/pl_00_00/pl_process_forgot_password_back.php/?trs=015df6fcf5bdcd4d9a339d5ca79d27a
    Chrome displays echo: "Redirect to: index.php" - as expected
```

So, when not using "header()" function the logic seems correct. As soon as I uncomment "header()" & "exit" and comment out echos and var_dumps, the problem appears and redirections are not happening. Here is the code I use (PASSWORD_RESET_PAGE & HOME_PAGE are constants defined elsewhere and both do not have function "header ("Location...")" that could cause redirect loop in them):

```
<?php 
# pl_process_forgot_password_back.php
require_once ("lib/required.php");

    # $_GET the string from url check and if matches, active and not expired display password change form
    $trs_from_email = $_GET['trs'];
    # retrieve user data    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE temporary_random_string    = '" . $trs_from_email . "'";

        $data_retrieved = sql_get_results_array($query); # retrieve data
        if (db_affected_rows() == 1) { # string matched - 1 row selected
            if ($data_retrieved[0]['random_string_active']){ # string active
                if ($data_retrieved[0]['random_string_expiry'] > time()){ # string not expired
                    # all ok - display reset password form                      
                    header ( "Location: " . PASSWORD_RESET_PAGE . '/?memid=' . $data_retrieved['id'] ); # send them to page with reset-password form
                    exit;   

echo '<br>' . '# all ok - display reset password form';
echo '<br>' . 'Redirect to: ' . PASSWORD_RESET_PAGE . '/?memid=' . $data_retrieved[0]['id'];
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($data_retrieved);
die;                        
                } else { # string expired
                    $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 17; # this is to popup request expiry message   
                } # /if string not expired
            } else { # string inactive
                $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 18; # request already processed message 
            } # /if string active
        } else { # string not matched
            $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 19; # string not matched message    
        } # /if valid string found

    header ( "Location: " . HOME_PAGE ); # send them to homepage and display popup error
    exit;

echo '<br>' . '# some error';
echo '<br>' . 'Redirect to: ' . HOME_PAGE;
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($data_retrieved);                      
die;                        
?>
```

Can anybody see why the above code is causing the "redirect loop"?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `die` and `exit` are equivalent, so pick one.
The script will not continue to execute after `die` or `exit` is hit in the script. Because of this you are cutting off your echo statements and var_dumps, which should be before header if you want them to be seen, but a redirect can be pretty quick which means they may not be seen at all.

a redirect loop can happen if you are redirecting to the same page that you are currently on or if you keep redirecting the user on subsequent pages. If you are sure this is not the case then you need to remove all the cookies and browser cache associated with your site which should fix the problem.

The following sample and place your code in the correct order.

```
<?php 
# pl_process_forgot_password_back.php
require_once ("lib/required.php");

    # $_GET the string from url check and if matches, active and not expired display password change form
    $trs_from_email = $_GET['trs'];
    # retrieve user data    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE temporary_random_string    = '" . $trs_from_email . "'";

        $data_retrieved = sql_get_results_array($query); # retrieve data
        if (db_affected_rows() == 1) { # string matched - 1 row selected
            if ($data_retrieved[0]['random_string_active']){ # string active
                if ($data_retrieved[0]['random_string_expiry'] > time()){ # string not expired
                    # all ok - display reset password form                      

                    echo '<br>' . '# all ok - display reset password form';
                    echo '<br>' . 'Redirect to: ' . PASSWORD_RESET_PAGE . '/?memid=' . $data_retrieved[0]['id'];
                    var_dump($_SESSION);
                    var_dump($data_retrieved);

                    header ( "Location: " . PASSWORD_RESET_PAGE . '/?memid=' . $data_retrieved['id'] ); # send them to page with reset-password form
                    exit; 
                } else { # string expired
                    $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 17; # this is to popup request expiry message   
                } # /if string not expired
            } else { # string inactive
                $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 18; # request already processed message 
            } # /if string active
        } else { # string not matched
            $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 19; # string not matched message    
        } # /if valid string found

    echo '<br>' . '# some error';
    echo '<br>' . 'Redirect to: ' . HOME_PAGE;
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    var_dump($data_retrieved);                        

    header ( "Location: " . HOME_PAGE ); # send them to homepage and display popup error
    exit;                    
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I only use echos and var_dumps for testing and do not expect to see them when header("Location.. & exit is on. Сould you please elaborate on cookies & cache... do I need to clear cookies every time I call header() function?

Comment: btw, I have removed cookies relating to localhost and cleared browsing history and that did not change the outcome.

Comment: @Voytek Do you get the same results in other browsers?

Comment: yes, Firefox complains differently to Chrome but with the same meaning while IE suggests invalidity of http://localhost... I just don't understand how these urls are formatted after redirect, seemas like concatenation.

Comment: I think I should add this info: All pages in my project are .php. While this particular page is pure PHP, the ones with html do follow jquery mobile principles. They are, however, "single-paged" for the time, i.e. they do not contain jq mobile's multi-page concept.

Comment: @Voytek the code is okay, so it seems the problem would be the URL that you are putting in. I suggest trying a different URL or two and see if that changes anything.

Comment: You've been great help. When I started typing some external URL I remembered reading about it having to be absolute so I've included http://host..etc... and it worked! So I've changed my links and it worked too, but not all. The two landing pages are identical for testing purposes, different names, but one link contains ".../?memid=99" at the end and that is causing the landing page display like it never loaded any css nor js even though it shows ok in "page  source". when I remove "/?memid..." it displays ok but of course I don't know who wants to reset the password...???

Comment: How else can I pass that "memid"? I tried $_SESSION['memid'] and it seems to work, the page is formatted ok and the value is there for me to work with. This is a password reset page though, so I'm concerned if $_SESSION is safe and good practice to use for that purpose?